# Is there a way to get graphene to work with django GenericRelation field?

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I have some django model generic relation fields that I want to appear in graphql queries. Does graphene support Generic types?

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

```
class Aparto(models.Model):
    agency = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Default')
    features = models.TextField()
    attachments = GenericRelation(Attachment)
```

graphene classes:

```
class ApartoType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Aparto
```

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all  = graphene.List(ApartoType)
    def resolve_all(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Aparto.objects.all()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

I expect the attachments field to appear in the graphql queries results. Only agency and features are showing.

Comment: You should include the graphene classes you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to expose `Attachment` to your schema. Graphene needs a `type` to work with for any related fields, so they need to be exposed as well.

In addition, you're likely going to want to resolve related `attachments`, so you'll want to add a resolver for them.

In your graphene classes, try:

```
class AttachmentType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Attachment

class ApartoType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Aparto

    attachments = graphene.List(AttachmentType)
    def resolve_attachments(root, info):
        return root.attachments.all()
```

Comment: This is not the answer I am looking for. How do you expose `content_object` from the `Attachment` class? Let's say the different related objects have different fields. How to dynamically alter the ObjectType depending on the class of the returned related object?

Comment: I achieve this trick by adding extra Charfield  in Attachment class.
`related_object_class = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)`
Given an object instance named obj, it is then sufficient to do:

   `related_object_class = obj.__class__.__name__`

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect, but this is how I did it:
First create a proxy class (I found that `abstract = True` also works), this should have all the fields that all the possible Generically Related objects can have.

```
class CatchAll(RelatedModelYouInheritFrom):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Then make a type for the proxy model

```
class CatchAllType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = CatchAll
        fields = ('some_var', 'other_var')
```

and in the resolver that returns instances of multiple classes: cast the instance as a CatchAll:

```
class ModelWithGenericForeignKeyType(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = ModelWithGenericForeignKey
        fields = ('other_var', 'some_var')

    generic_relation = graphene.Field(CatchAllType)


    def resolve_generic_relation(self, info, **kwargs):
        d = self.generic_relation.__dict__  # turn the model in a dict
        d.pop('_state')  # remove the state
        return CatchAll(**d)  # cast the object of any class into the CatchAll
```