# graphene nodes for model inheriting from abstract superclass

Tags: graphene-django

I have a schema of 2 classes:

```
class Anomaly(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Anomaly


class Batch(LoggedModel):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Batch
```

where `LoggedModel` is

```
class LoggedModel(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.LoggedModel
```

originally both inherited from `DjangoObjectType` but then neither of the two was exposing a field `logs` defined in the superclass of the model

```
class LoggedModel(models.Model):
    recursive_field = "parent_model"
    logs = models.ManyToManyField(Log, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Anomaly(LoggedModel):
    ...

class Batch(LoggedModel):
    anomalies = models.ManyToManyField(Anomaly)
```

Now, after declaring in the schema Batch a subclass of LoggedModel instead of DjangoObjectType, logs is exposed for both classes. Anyone can shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

Any related fields that you wish to have in your models need to be explicitly declared, as you've done in your second example. In the first example, logs isn't automagically exposed even though it exists, I assume, in the model definition.

In the second, it *is* exposed in `LoggedModel`, thus also for `Anomaly` and `Batch`.

You should find that they both work simply as `DjangoObjectType`s if you explicitly expose logs in them.

Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56173485/214150

Comment: Just to clarify the above is the code that is running right now. The upper part is the schema and the lower part is the model. `logs` is a field in the abstract model `LoggedModel`. If I now change just the inheritance for `Batch` from `LoggedModel` to `DjangoObjectType` it stops working.